# Trying to translate a text into another text by character substitution, output is incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I am writing a code and i am not getting the desired output.It would be great if anyone can help me by pointing out what i am doing wrong.My code is:

```
shift = input()

word_original = input()
corrected_word = ""

keyboard_characters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjkl;zxcvbnm,./"

if shift == "R":
    for i in range(len(shift)-1):
        ind = keyboard_characters.find(shift[i]) + 1
        corrected_word = corrected_word + keyboard_characters[ind]

else:
    for i in range(len(shift)-1):
        ind = keyboard_characters.find(shift[i]) - 1
        corrected_word = corrected_word + keyboard_characters[ind]


print(len(corrected_word))
```

Here according to me i am supposed to be getting the corrected_word but instead it is giving its length to be 0 ,i.e, it is just what i had defined it initially,i.e, empty string

Comment: You haven't specified what your code is supposed to do, but if `shift` is one character long, `range(len(shift)-1)` is empty, so your `for` loop will run zero times. You don't seem to be using your `word_original` string at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your loop operates on `for i in range(len(shift)-1):` where you ment to use `for i in range(len(word_original )-1):`.

Iterating by index over a string is not needed here, you could simply go for

```
for letter in word_original:
    substIdx = keyboard_characters.find(letter) + 1 
    [...]
```

But this will get you out of bounds error if your text contains `'/'` as your index is now outside of  `keyboard_characters` length. Also you do not handle non-existent mappings (f.e. space) for which find will return a value thats probably not correct.

*Fix of your code:*

Strings are immutables. by using `s = s + "..."` you are creating lots of throw-away `strings` wich takes perfomance. Use a `list` instead and `''.join(mylist)` afterwards to get the string.

```
shift = input() 
word_original = input()
corrected_word = []

keyboard_characters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjkl;zxcvbnm,./"
keyset = set(keyboard_characters) # tesint for 'in' faster on sets
lenk = len(keyboard_characters)   # compute once, use often

if shift == "R":
    for letter in word_original:
        if letter not in keyset: # no substitution? use as is
            corrected_word.append( letter )
            continue
        ind = keyboard_characters.find(letter) + 1

        if ind == lenk:
            ind = 0 # wrap around
        corrected_word.append(keyboard_characters[ind])

else:
    for letter in word_original:
        if letter not in keyset: # no substitution? use as is
            corrected_word.append( letter )
            continue
        ind = keyboard_characters.find(letter) - 1

        if ind < 0:
            ind = lenk # wrap around
        corrected_word.append( keyboard_characters[ind] )

corrected_word_str = ''.join(corrected_word)

print(corrected_word_str)
```

---

*Better way to solve this task:*

What you try to code already has a solution using python - for replacing something, `dict`s are great as you mapp a key to a value. For strings there are even convenience functions that build the dict for you:

Readup:

- [str.translate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)
- [str.maketrans()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)

If a character is not present in the lookup, it is used as is (space f.e.)

```
keyboard_characters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjkl;zxcvbnm,./"

# create replace dicts
# this mapps around - / is "before" q and q is "after" /
forward = str.maketrans(keyboard_characters,
                        keyboard_characters[1:] + keyboard_characters[0])

backward = str.maketrans(keyboard_characters,
                         keyboard_characters[-1] + keyboard_characters[:-1])

word_original = input()

forw = word_original.translate(forward)
back = word_original.translate(backward)

print(word_original, forw, back, sep="\n\n")
```

Output:

```
# original text
some text with ;and / in it

# forward
dp,r yrcy eoyj zsmf q om oy

# backward
ainw rwzr qurg lpbs . ub ur
```